# Windows 8 Store app : Background task interval between reexecution

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

when i read about Windows 8 store app i found that on MSDN :

[Supporting your app with background tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx)

CPU usage is limited as follows:

If App not on lock screen : CPU usage quota ( 1 second) &
Refresh time (2 hours )

If App on the lock screen: CPU usage quota ( 2 hours ) &
Refresh time (15 minutes)

does that mean that i can't run background task every (10 ) miuntes ? only i will restricted with minimum (15) minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.  See the [TimeTrigger class docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.timetrigger.aspx) ...

> Note  If FreshnessTime is set to less than 15 minutes, an exception is
>   thrown when attempting to register the background task.

There is a detailed discussion of this in the [Introduction to Background Tasks whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411).

Comment: This is 100% perfect. Thanks for the clarification.